# MonoDevelop, как установить версию 5.9 на Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ubuntu, monodevelop

Доброго дня, уважаемые гуру Linux
Пытаюсь себе поставить версию MonoDevelop посвежее на  Ubuntu 14.04. Из центра приложений удалось поставить лишь 4.02. Выполнял команды, которые были указаны на странице 
http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/#modmono-ubuntu-1310-and-later-debian-80-and-later
но после этого из репозиториев видна все та же версия 4.02

Comment: `apt-get update` не забыли выполнить после добавления файла в `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`?

Answer (score 1):

Версия из репозиториев opensuse для xUbuntu и подобных:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/tpokorra:/mono/xUbuntu_15.04/ /' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-opt.list"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mono-opt
```

И добавляем ключ репозитория в apt
wget

```
http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:tpokorra:mono/xUbuntu_15.04/Release.key
sudo apt-key add - < Release.key
```

[Ссылка на источник](http://software.opensuse.org/download/package?project=home:tpokorra:mono&package=mono-opt)

---

Есть другой способ. Самостоятельно найдите и скачайте нужную вам версию ПО monodevelop debian(.deb) пакетом. После скачивания введите в консоль команду

```
sudo dpkg -i packagename.deb
```